# Render content after given block in view helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view helper method that takes a block. Render that block is no problem, but when I try to add content after the block is rendered, it does not work.

```
  def validation_div(&block)
    content_tag :div do
      yield
      content_tag :div do
        'This content is never rendered!'
      end
    end
  end
```

The above code just yields the block and skips the other content. I have also tried with: `content_for`, `capture`, `concat` and `with_output_buffer` without any success. As you notice, I don't really understand how these methods work... But my question is: how to render something after the given block is rendered. Thanks!

Comment: Capture is most likely what you want to do - can you post the code where you pass the block to validation_div

Comment: @trh `<%= validation_div do %> <p>This is renedered</p> <% end %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at a content_tag definition, you see it only outputs one tag, one class, and one content.  You're trying to get it out out multiple contents so you'll need to join them.

```
def validation_div(&block)
  content = capture(&block)
  content_tag :div do
    content + content_tag(:div , "This content is never rendered!")
  end
end
```